# Make a child div as tall as an auto height parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper element that contains two floated elements the contentArea and sidebar. contentArea has the most content and therefore determines the height of the wrapper element. I want the sidebar to touch the wrapper div's bottom edge as well. How do I do that. It's a basic wordpress blog layout.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <div id="content">
        GROWS REALLY TALL AS HAS SO MUCH CONTENT
        GROWS REALLY TALL AS HAS SO MUCH CONTENT
        GROWS REALLY TALL AS HAS SO MUCH CONTENT
        GROWS REALLY TALL AS HAS SO MUCH CONTENT
        GROWS REALLY TALL AS HAS SO MUCH CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        WANT'S TO BE AS TALL AS CONTENT.
        height:100%;   /*  doesn't work  */
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
#content{
    height:auto;
    width:625px;
}
#sidebar{
    height:100%;
    width:335px;
}
```

Appreciate all the help.

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand, the sidebar IS touching the bottom of the wrapper (at least in this code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is [that](http://jsfiddle.net/aFdzQ/) what you are looking for?

Comment: YES!  thank you so much...I had a feeling I would have to resort to js at the end... you saved my design...Thank you!

Comment: @RCNeil, no, it's just CSS. You shouldn't use JavaScript for styling unless you can't do it with CSS.